# Парсинг xml (android файлы)

Tags: c#, xml, парсер

Каким методом можно спарсить на C# вот такой xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <public type="attr" name="twSoftkeyItemStyle" id="0x7f010000" />
    <public type="attr" name="twSoftkeyItemType" id="0x7f010001" />
    <public type="attr" name="twSoftkeyItemText" id="0x7f010002" />
    <public type="attr" name="twSoftkeyItemImage" id="0x7f010003" />
</resources>
```

Спарсить нужно все "public", а точнее значения type name id.
Так же интересует вопрос, как удалить строку public по name из xml файла и сохранить его.

Answer (score 1):

Запросто. Положите ваш XML в `XDocument` (`XDocument.Load` или `XDocument.Parse`), дальше

```
doc.Descendants("public").Attributes("id").Select(a => a.Value)
```

Если вам нужны числа, то

```
doc.Descendants("public").Attributes("id").Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.Value, 16));
```

---

Чтобы удалить узел по атрибуту, можно сделать, например, так:

```
var attributesToDelete =
    doc.Descendants("public")
       .Attributes("name")
       .Where(a => a.Value == <здесь ваше значение>)
       .ToList();
foreach (var attr in attributesToDelete)
    attr.Parent.Remove();
```

Сохраняется обновлённый `XDocument` как обычно, через `Save`.

Comment: Работает, но как быть если нужно получить одновременно type и name ?

Comment: @LorDo: Встречный вопрос — а в каком виде вы хотите их получить?

Comment: C этим я уже разобрался, остался открытым вопрос, как удалить какую-то строку по name и сохранить измененный xml.

Comment: @LorDo: Дополнил ответ, разбирайтесь.